# Is there an inequality that $\|a+b\|^2 \le \|a\|^2 + \|b\|^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

For a norm $\|\cdot\|$ by triangle inequality we have $\|a+b\| \le \|a\| + \|b\|$ and by Cauchy–Schwarz inequality $\|ab\| \le \|a\|\|b\|$, but I am not sure if the following inequality holds always true: $\|a+b\|^2 \le \|a\|^2 + \|b\|^2$.

Thanks for the answers!

Then, let's say $\|a+b\|^2 \lesssim \|a\|^2 + \|b\|^2$, is that true?

Comment: Take $a=b$ non zero.

Comment: Since $\|a+b\|^2=\|a\|^2+2a\cdot b\|b\|^2$, that inequality hinges on if $a\cdot b$ is positive or negative.

Comment: $\| a+b \|^2\leq 2(\|a\|^2+\|b\|^2)$

Comment: Thanks! I think I should use "$\lesssim$" instead of "$\le$" as in the textbook did

Answer (score 2):

If we have an inner product $\langle . | . \rangle$, then:
$$
||a+b||^2 = \langle a+b | a+b \rangle = \langle a | a \rangle +2\langle a | b \rangle + \langle b | b \rangle = ||a||^2+||b||^2+2\langle a | b \rangle
$$
Thus your assertion does not hold for say: $a=\alpha b$ with $\alpha>0$.

Comment: So $\|a+b\|^2 \le 2(\|a\|^2 + \|b\|^2)$ is true?

Comment: Yes because then you would have $2 \langle a|b \rangle \leq \langle a|a \rangle + \langle b|b \rangle$ i.e. $0\leq \langle b-a|b-a \rangle = ||b-a||^2$ which holds

Comment: Thank you very much! By the way, can we say $\|ab\|\le\|a\|\|b\|$ holds by Cauchy–Schwarz inequality? I saw Cauchy–Schwarz inequality in textbook is always an inner product form $|<a,b>|$ on LHS.

Comment: No it is not possible, that would be a [normed algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_algebra). $|\langle a,b \rangle|$ and $||ab||$ are nothing alike and actually, in a vector space, $ab$ makes no sense at all since there is no multiplication in vector spaces.

Comment: Well. Assume $a$, $b$ are two functions integrable over the domain $\Omega$ for the norm, then can we say $\|a b\|_{\Omega} \le \|a\|_{\Omega} \|b\|_{\Omega}$, where $ab$ means the product of the two functions?

Comment: Counterexample: let $\Omega = [0,1]$ , $f(x)=g(x)=x$ and $||u||_\Omega = \int_\Omega |u(x)|dx$ (I will let you check that it is indeed a [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Definition) ). Then $||fg||_\Omega=\frac{1}{3}>||f||_\Omega ||g||_\Omega=\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 2):

No, take $a=b=1$. Then you get $\|a+b\|^2=4$ and $\|a\|^2=\|b\|^2=1$, so $4\le 1+1$ does not hold.

Answer (score 1):

If $a=b\neq 0$ then $||a+b\|^2=4\|a\|^2\neq \|a\|^2+\|a\|^2=2\|a\|^2$.

But you could prove that $x\to \|x\|^2$ is a convex function, i.e. $\|sa+tb\|^2\leq s\|a\|^2+t\|b\|^2$ whenever $s+t=1$ and $ s,t\geq 0$.

So in particular if $s=t=\frac 12$ then $\|a+b\|^2\leq 2(\|a\|^2+\|b\|^2)$